# Mysql Query Between two colum with start_date and end_date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table data.

| ID | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-03 1:30:01 | 2021-05-03 2:00:01 |
| 2 | 2021-05-03 2:00:02 | 2021-05-03 2:30:02 |
| 3 | 2021-05-03 2:30:03 | 2021-05-03 3:00:03 |
| 4 | 2021-05-03 3:00:03 | 2021-05-03 4:00:03 |

You can recreate it using the following sql

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`ID`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES
(1, '2021-05-03 01:30:01', '2021-05-03 02:00:01'),
(2, '2021-05-03 02:00:02', '2021-05-03 02:30:02'),
(3, '2021-05-03 02:30:03', '2021-05-03 03:00:03'),
(4, '2021-05-03 03:00:03', '2021-05-03 04:00:03');
```

What I need is to get the row between start_date and end_date.

I can just do a

```sql
select * from test_table 
 where end_date BETWEEN '2021-05-03 2:30:03' AND '2021-05-03 4:00:00'
```

Result is
[image]
The problem using the query above is it is not between `start_date` and `end_date`.

So now I tried

```sql
select * from test_table 
 where start_date >= '2021-05-03 2:30:03' AND end_date <= '2021-05-03 4:00:00'
```

[image]
I have issue with the last query because it doesn't give me row 3 and row 4.

I wanted to get row 3 and row 4 because the date is between '2021-05-03 2:30:03' and '2021-05-03 4:00:00'. Basically, I need to get this row because I am calculating time.

| ID | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-05-03 2:30:03 | 2021-05-03 3:00:03 |
| 4 | 2021-05-03 3:00:03 | 2021-05-03 4:00:03 |

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of column `start_date` and column `end_date`?

Comment: @Abra the type is datetime

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice that the end time in row 4 is `4:00:03` which is after the time in your criteria, i.e. `4:00:00`, so why would row 4 be included in your results?

Comment: I believe 2021-05-03 3:59:00 is between '2021-05-03 2:30:03' and '2021-05-03 4:00:00'. Maybe I should change my question? because I need to count the time that's why I need it to be part of the result.

Comment: But row 4 isn't within the parameters!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want any rows that *intersect* with your interval.  That means that they start before the end of the interval and begin after the interval begins.

`BETWEEN` is not the right logic:

```
select *
from test_table 
where start_date < '2021-05-03 4:00:00' and
      end_date > '2021-05-03 2:30:03' ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67ae90e0cc909e3cff57fdef6dc129d0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you missed `miliseconds` part for which you are getting the records with ID 3.

```
select * from test_table where start_date >= '2021-05-03 2:30:03'
 AND end_date <= '2021-05-03 4:00:03'
```

it should give you records with ID 3 and 4.